# How to add "centered masonry" on isotope using data-attribute

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute, masonry, jquery-isotope

I'am using isotope with data-attribute. I want to add on each filter [Centered Masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html) with data-centered="true/false". Any suggestions?

```js
$('.js-isotope').imagesLoaded( function() {
  $('.js-isotope').isotope('layout');
});
```

```html
<div class="row grid js-isotope" data-isotope-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "layoutMode": "masonry"}'>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 grid-item">
     ...
   </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 grid-item">
     ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 grid-item">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Isotope v2 use `isFitWidth` http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#isfitwidth

```
masonry: {
  columnWidth: 100,
  isFitWidth: true
}
```

css

```
/* center container with CSS */
    .grid {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/BptxJ

Comment: Thank you. That helped a little bit, but instead of fixed width I'm using bootstrap `.col-*`. And when I filter items, `.row` collapses to `.col-*` padding only because `.row` items depends of their parrent, so my item width is `2rem`.

Comment: so try masonry: {
  columnWidth: '.grid-item',
  isFitWidth: true
}

Comment: Thats what I already tryed. As I said, `col-*` width is in `%` and they depends of `.row`. It's not so confusing but it's hard to explain.